# open SearchableSpinner programmatically

Tags: android, android-spinner

I use [SearchableSpinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) widget, it is a great spinner, but there is a problem when I want to open the spinner by clicking on a button.

I used `performClick()` but instead of showing the searchable dialog, the standard one shows up, the searchable dialog appears only if the user clicks on the spinner, I also tried `callOnClick()` and didn't work.

Searchable Dialog:

[image]

Standard Spinner:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
yourSearchableSpinner.onTouch(view, MotionEvent.obtain(1, 1, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1, 1, 1));
```

In fragment, you can get view as:

```
View view;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.view = view;
    ...
}
```

In activity, you can get view as:

```
View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    view = findViewById(R.id.your_root_view);
    ...
}
```